# is it safe or not to replace my old laptop battery's cells which can increase its Ampere hours from 6600 mah to 13200 mah?

Tags: batteries, laptop

My old laptop battery's total designed power is 6600 mah and if i replace its cells from Samsung rechargeable cells 3.7V and 2200mah per cell.it will increase battery's power from 6600mAh to 13200 mAh. iwana ask about that is it safe or not?

Comment: 6 cells a 2200mAh equals 4400mAh in the usual laptop 3s2p configuration. Unsafe since your laptop might draw too much current.

Comment: You need to specify original mAh or whole pack AND voltage. At least. 
Note that for series cells V adds but mAh is unchanged. For parallel cells mAh add but V is unchanged. Original 6600 is probably already ?S3P of 2200 mAh cells./

Answer (score 1):

It probably won't even do what you want.

Your laptop cells are probably in series; if so, you will actually cut the lifetime by 2/3, since series batteries don't add up mAH capacities.  The power capacity increases because the voltage is higher, but the same current flows through all of them at once.  If it's a 3s2p configuration, you'll reduce it by 1/3.

Your Samsung "battery" is what is called a "pack," meaning one or more cells with additional circuitry.  The same is true for your laptop battery.  You're proposing replacing the cells in the laptop pack with Samsung packs.  This *might* be safe, but lots of things could go wrong that I can't predict, so I don't recommend it.

If I'm correct about the wiring and you attempt the replacement, you'll be charging the Samsung packs at about 3X the recommended rate.  This is, by definition, not recommended.

There are other considerations, but if you're not clear on these, you'd probably be best served not taking apart batteries, packs, or particularly cells.